# Missing images on carousel view from urls

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, carousel

I'm making an app with Xamarin Form that should work both on iOS and Android, I have a carousel view with an image inside, so I have tried making a carousel with a cell using this nugget: [URL](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading)

while working fine on iOS on android the cell keeps crashing so I've changed with a cell containing only one image with a binding on the URL
now everything working but the are sono images sporadically missing inside the carousel.

Am I missing something? is there a nugget package for xamarin form for caching displaying correctly all the images?

thanks

making FFImage.Loading working on Android with no success

android cell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:ffimage="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CTSApp.Utility" 
             x:Class="CTSApp.Celle.cella_volantino_android">
    <ContentView.Content>
         <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <local:PinchToZoomContainer>
                    <local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
                  <Image Source="{Binding url}" HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" 
                         VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" />
                   </local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
                </local:PinchToZoomContainer>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

iOS cell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ffimage="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
             xmlns:fftransf="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Transformations;assembly=FFImageLoading.Transformations"

    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CTSApp.Utility" x:Class="CTSApp.Celle.cella_volantino">
        <ContentView.Content>
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                     <local:PinchToZoomContainer>
                        <local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
                            <ffimage:CachedImage Grid.RowSpan="2" Aspect="AspectFill"
                                     Source="{Binding url}"
                                     DownsampleToViewSize="false"
                                     LoadingPlaceholder="placeholder.png"
                                     ErrorPlaceholder="placeholder.png"
                                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <ffimage:CachedImage.CacheDuration>
                                    <x:TimeSpan>0,0,15,0</x:TimeSpan>
                                </ffimage:CachedImage.CacheDuration>
                          </ffimage:CachedImage>
                        </local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
                    </local:PinchToZoomContainer>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </ContentView.Content>
    </ContentView>
```

thanks for help.

**EDIT**

Here is my main activity:

```
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Plugin.FirebasePushNotification;
using Firebase;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
using Plugin.Permissions;
using Xamarin;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Android.Content.Res;
using SegmentedControl.FormsPlugin.Android;
using ZXing.Mobile;

namespace CTSApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "CTSApp", Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher", Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity

    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);


            MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, bundle);
            ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
            FFImageLoading.Forms.Droid.CachedImageRenderer.Init(enableFastRenderer: true);
            Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);
            SegmentedControlRenderer.Init();
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(Intent);

            LoadApplication(new App());


        }


        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.PermissionsHandler.OnRequestPermissionsResult (requestCode, permissions, grantResults);           

        }
    }
}
```

FFImageLoader version 2.4.3.840
Xamarin form version 2.50

***EDIT 2***

Maybe I've found the problem, here is the new definitive cell I'm using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:ffimage="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CTSApp.Utility" 
             x:Class="CTSApp.Celle.cella_volantino_android">
    <ContentView.Content>
         <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <local:PinchToZoomContainer>
                    <local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
                  <Image Source="{Binding url}" HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" 
                         VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" >
                        <Image.Source>
                        <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding url}" 
                            CacheValidity="14" 
                            CachingEnabled="true"/>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                   </local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
                </local:PinchToZoomContainer>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Now I'm using the standard image with caching , now on iOS everything works fine , on android I'm getting error from some pages

> ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Could not retrieve image or image data was invalid: Uri:

that obviously does not load, I've followed the tutorial here
https://doumer.me/resolve-image-loading-error-in-xamarin-forms/

Still no luck, but if I turn the phone horizontally the image load correctly, I really have no clue

video here:

https://streamable.com/rk1rv

Comment: Why do you have two different cells in ios and android?

Comment: Because the iOS cell crash on android with no explanation , I want to understand why a cell with an immageview does not render properly on android

Comment: Have you initialized FFImageLoading in Android MainActivity?

Comment: Added Main Activity class for you ;)

Comment: @GiulioSerra Where you used carousel view,  not seeing it in xaml code.And you can show code about model.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT added a video with the real cause , is not the model

Comment: @GiulioSerra According to the video, the image seems to be not loaded in time. When the horizontal and vertical screens are switched, the scrolling of the srollview will be triggered, resulting in the image being displayed. On the one hand, you have a large number of images loaded, on the other hand, it is possible that the data size of the image is relatively large, and it takes a lot of time to load a large number of images at one time.

Comment: @GiulioSerra You may try the CarouselView control and see if his effect will be better. If you want to optimize on Android, try not to make the image url address not too long, and use the thread to load the image asynchronously should not appear this phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample with **CarouselView** to show image.All can work in IOS and Android.If want to use `ffimage:CachedImage` ,replacing `Image` with it.

Here is **Xaml** code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <CarouselView x:Name="carousel" ItemsSource="{Binding uris}">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image
                    x:Name="PlantPicture"
                    Source="{Binding uri}"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="150"
                    HeightRequest="150">
                </Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
</StackLayout>
```

Model code :

```
public class FloraData
{
    public class StringData
    {
        public string uri { get; set; }
    }

    public List<StringData> uris { get; set; }

    public FloraData()
    {
        uris = new List<StringData>() { new StringData() { uri = "https://static.inaturalist.org/photos/504134/medium.jpg?1379628103" },
                                            new StringData() { uri = "https://static.inaturalist.org/photos/8784478/small.jpg?1499006293" },
                                            new StringData() { uri = "https://api.idigbio.org/v2/media/23cbb9eb2750e80848ac95b5d2919323?size=thumbnail" },
                                            new StringData() { uri = "https://api.idigbio.org/v2/media/c085496285be91ace0768eb517cc704b?size=thumbnail" },
                                            new StringData() { uri = "http://swbiodiversity.org/imglib/arizona/IND/IND-0049/IND-0049216_1491615930_tn.jpg" }};
    }
}
```

Finally , **ContentPage.cs** BindingContext :

```
FloraData floraData = new FloraData();
carousel.BindingContext = floraData;
```

Comment: thanks but It wasn't releated to code , It was a nugget problem

Comment: @GiulioSerra Okey, got it. :)